# ¿Cómo puedo eliminar los saltos de línea del código de una variable en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo el siguiente código del ejemplo. Cuando yo pulso el botón *Guardar en variable*, el código HTML que se ingrese en el `<textarea>` se guardará en una variable. El problema es que hay saltos de línea aplicados en el textarea. Estaría permitido, por decirlo de alguna manera, que no hubiera problema en ingresar saltos de línea en el textarea, puesto que luego Javascript borraría dichos saltos sin afectar el código. Entonces, ¿cómo puedo eliminar dichos saltos de línea para que no haya errores usando Javascript? Gracias de antemano

```js
function guardar() {
 var codigodeltextarea = document.getElementById("codigo").value
 console.log(codigodeltextarea);
}
```

```html
<textarea id="codigo" style="height:118px;width:358px;"><h2>Título de página</h2>
<p>Texto normal</p></textarea>
<br>
<button onclick="guardar()">Guardar en variable</button>
```

Comment: Saludos. Si no quieres salto de línea en un dato lo idóneo es usar `input` en vez de `textarea`; hay que considerar la experiencia del usuario, si observa un área para entrada de datos que permita incluso texto enriquecido lo aprovechara; no por abusar, sino por que así se le da a entender es permitido/necesario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para eliminar todos los saltos de línea, puedes utilizar la función replace

```
<textarea id="codigo" style="height:118px;width:358px;"><h2>Título de página</h2>
<p>Texto normal</p></textarea>
<br>
<button onclick="guardar()">Guardar en variable</button>
```

JavaScript

```
function guardar() {
 var codigodeltextarea = document.getElementById("codigo").value
 var textarea = codigodeltextarea.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "")
 console.log(textarea);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Existe una función propia de Javascript que te permite hacer eso, elimina todos lo que se considera "whitespace" (Caracteres de salto de línea, espacios , retornos de carro etc...) al inicio y al final de un string.
Ejemplo

```js
const myString = '       Hola mundo   ';
const myNewString = myString.trim();

console.log(myNewString);
```

Usualmente cuando quieres "Limpiar texto" proviniendo de un `input` es la mejor y más corta forma de hacerlo.

Si quieres ver más información sobre esta función te recomiendo el siguiente enlace: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/Trim